# WinInet Access Violation in HttpOpenRequest()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking

I am trying to upload a file to a PHP page using WinInet.  I'm getting an Access Violation on one of the functions, but can't see why.  I've built the code from an example page.

Here is the code:

```cpp
HINTERNET aInternet=InternetOpen("My-Custom-Agent/1.0",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
HINTERNET aConnect=InternetConnect(aInternet,"www.myserver.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
if (aConnect)
{
    HINTERNET aRequest=HttpOpenRequest(aConnect, (const char*)"POST","myphppage.php", NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0",0,1);
    // ^^
    // Exception happens on this line
    // Exception thrown at 0x70C85B7C (ininet.dll) in TestApp.exe:
    // 0xC00000005: Access violation reading location 0x002A2F2A
    //
}
```

When I download from the server with `InternetOpenURL()`, everything seems fine.  It just doesn't like what I'm doing somewhere here.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in C++ all literal strings are really constant arrays of characters, which decays to pointers to constant characters (i.e. `const char*`). In other words, the cast in `(const char*)"POST"` is not needed. In fact, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast like that you should take it as a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Coming back to the C-style cast being wrong, the string `"*/*\0"` will decay to a pointer of the type `const char*`. It's most definitely not possible to use it as a pointer to a pointer (what you try to with the cast to `const char**`). And is very likely the cause of the crash. If you remove the cast the compiler should (rightly) complain. Casting away such complaints is not a good idea.

Comment: Some programmer dude, this was the answer.  But remy (below) also gave a working answer, but not the specifics.  Since you answered first, if you want to put an answer below, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: @KiraHoneybee how is my answer not providing specifics?

Comment: *reading location **0x002A2F2A*** - this is `"*/*"` binary value as is. string data interpreted as pointer. error already give you strong hint

Comment: Hi Remy, the most value I got out of some programmer dude was the (slap forehead) realization that the compiler would not cast a string with \0 in it as an array of types.  I had actually copied that code elsewhere without thinking.  Anyway, some programmer dude isn't back to claim credit, so I am marking yours as the answer.

Comment: @KiraHoneybee wow, don't I feel special now. This issue has *absolutely nothing* to do with `\0`, and *everything* to do with you passing a bad pointer to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`HttpOpenRequest()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpopenrequesta):

> `[in] lplpszAcceptTypes`
>
> A pointer to **a null-terminated array** of strings that indicates media types accepted by the client. Here is an example.
>
> `PCTSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {_T("text/*"), NULL};`
>
> Failing to properly terminate the array with a NULL pointer will cause a crash.

You are passing in a pointer to a single null-terminated string, incorrectly type-casted to `const char**`:

```
lplpszAcceptTypes -> "*/*"
```

But the function requires a pointer to an **array** of pointers to null-terminated strings, where the last element in the array must be NULL to terminate the array (since there is no function parameter to specify the number of elements in the array):

```
                     -----
lplpszAcceptTypes -> | 0 | -> "*/*"
                     |---|
                     | 1 | -> NULL
                     -----
```

See the difference?

The function is misinterpreting the *content* of your string literal as if it were a pointer, which it is not, hence the AV crash.  The address where the AV is occurring, `0x002A2F2A`, is literally the same bytes as the content of your string literal (`"*/*“` = `0x2A 0x2F 0x2A 0x00`).

You need to use this instead:

```cpp
LPCSTR rgpszAcceptTypes[] = {"*/*", NULL};
HINTERNET aRequest = HttpOpenRequest(aConnect, "POST", "myphppage.php", NULL, NULL, rgpszAcceptTypes, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Hi, the "\0" in my string expands to a null (confirmed it by checking bytes).  Here's another wrinkle-- it works okay if NOT using the debugger.

Comment: @KiraHoneybee a string literal has an implicit `'\0'` added by the compiler, so you don't need to add your own. The string literal `"*/*"` is the array`{'*', '/', '*', '\0'}`. By adding a `'\0'` manually, you are simply extending the array to `{'*', '/', '*', '\0', '\0'}`, which has no effect whatsoever on how the function processes your data. What does affect it is the layout of the string data in memory, and what you were originally passing in was the completely wrong layout, hence the crash